# Iterating over my sorted pandas dataframe to groupby is extremely slow. Any alternatives?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I want to perform a custom groupby in my pandas dataframe. I have the following dataframe:

```
OwnerUserId  AnswerCount  CommentCount    Id             CreationDate
   3834.0          7.0               4    85  2009-06-28 11:31:29.417
      0.0          2.0               0   469  2009-06-29 07:46:13.990
  83871.0          3.0               2   918  2009-06-30 01:04:50.903
  77090.0          1.0               1  1094  2009-06-30 13:11:48.333
 130090.0          1.0               2  1208  2009-06-30 16:15:07.673
       ..          ..                ..    ..                      ..
```

For each 'Id_q' (question), I want to groupby all the entries made by the 'OwnerUserId' before the 'CreationDate' of the question.
In order to do this, I sorted with 'CreationDate', and perform groupby for each entry in a for loop. The code is provided below. However, I have 40K rows, which makes this operation extremely slow. 
Are there any faster ways to do this?

```
result_df = pd.DataFrame()
df = df.sort_values(["CreationDate"]) #sorting 
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    head_df = df.head(i)
    head_df = head_df[head_df.OwnerUserId == row.OwnerUserId]
    grouped_df = head_df.groupby('OwnerUserId', 
as_index=0).agg({'Id':"count",'CommentCount': "sum", 'AnswerCount': 'sum'})
    result_df = result_df.append(grouped_df)
```

I need the result_df as my output.

Comment: You can probably replace your loop. Add an example dataset (5-10) rows and explain what you try to do, and at the end add an expected output also, so we can see what your output looks like

Comment: It's slow because you're doing the same thing 40k times. It would be helpful to know _WHY_ you're trying to compute and save 40k groupby DFs. I feel like there may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) happening here

Comment: Edited the question based on your comments.

Comment: I am working on Stack Overflow data by the way :). I want to get the sum of all the comments and answers posted by on a Questioner's previous questions, she posted before a specific question.

Comment: I'm still not understanding your desired output. Can you provide a [mcve] with a sample input and output? It sounds like you want a `df.groupby(['OwnerUserID','Id']).count()` or something with `cumsum()` or `cumcount()`